# SwiftUI animation of a ScrollView

Tags: swiftui

I have two views (VStacks) one on top of the other in a ZStack

The first VStack that is behind the second view is used like a menu. The second view that is on top, is the main application view.

When i click on a button i'm scaling down the main view and move it a bit to the right side of the screen to show the menu.

I have a ScrollView inside the main view every time i scale down or up the main view, the animation doesn't work smoothly the page flickers and it looks ugly. if i remove the ScrollView it works perfectly fine.

I tried to replace the ScrollView with a List but it didn't solve the problem the flickering remains the same.

Is there any way to fix this glitch?

below is a sample code

```
struct ContentView: View {
 var body: some View {

ZStack {

 Menu()

VStack {

  ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {

  VStack(spacing:0) {

     Header()

     MainAppView()

     }

  }

TabBar()

}

.scaleEffect(self.openMenu ? 0.5 : 1, anchor: UnitPoint(x: 1.5, y: 0.5))

.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2))

}

}

}
```

[Please click to check animated gif example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5UJm.gif)

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is, to make screenshot of the flickering view and then do the animation with the screenshot which you just add on the real view. After the animation just remove the screenshot. Of course you have to make the screenshot programmatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i will have a problem when the user clicks and switches to another page, then the new page will flicker when it goes back to full screen since it's not gonna be a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

I can't repeat all the behavior, because of lack of code. I think you have this problem, because you're scaling down `ScrollView` and it recomputes all the content. Try just to make some offset for it, instead of scaling and there should be no flickers:

```swift
// replace this
.scaleEffect(self.openMenu ? 0.5 : 1, anchor: UnitPoint(x: 1.5, y: 0.5))

// with this:
.offset(x: self.openMenu ? 300 : 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have noticed something though, if i scale down without playing with the anchor values there is no flickering, it works well and smooth                     but the view won't scale in the right place it will scale in the top left corner and the menu will remain covered. but as soon as i change the y value the flickering appears.

Comment: @Philippe, try to scale and make offset like in my answer, but with y position too. Your view should scale down and go to a new position smoothly